# Stack Exchange Chat logs me out every 3 minutes

Tags: support, status-completed, chat, stackexchange-2.0, login

I tried to log in via [the ghetto login button](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/chat-stackexchange-login/), via StackAuth on the room list, via StackAuth on the login page, via StackAuth after logging in and out of a SE site (SF), via the 'chat' button on Gaming...

...but no matter what I do, today I'm consistently being logged out.

The 5 minutes figure is a guess, by the way -- the only hint of my being logged off is the *You must login to post* message I get when I eventually decide to log back in.

I am on a very slow, very unreliable, very infuriating "3.5G" mobile connection that makes me crave for proper dialup.

---

Here's a sample of my javascript console output (with XHR logging turned on)

```
    XHR finished loading: "http://chat.stackexchange.com/chats/35/messages/new".
12× XHR finished loading: "http://chat.stackexchange.com/events".
 5× POST http://chat.stackexchange.com/events undefined (undefined)
                                                                jquery.min.js:130
```

When those errors start accumulating, duplicating the tab reveals I've been logged out.

---

I think it is lost on @drach and some commenters that:

- **I do not get the same issue on chat.meta.stackoverflow.com**
- I cannot reproduce this on any other internet site either.
- I've used this same horrible connection in the past few days without this problem.
- Grace has been able to reproduce this issue without being on a similarly poor connection.

Comment: I _can't_ repro the issue on MSO chat.

Comment: You, now? This is like some kind of infectious plague that just spreads from one person to the next, ruining their day. Maybe I gave it to you. I think I might've gotten it from Mrozek, who probably got it from rchern... so I think we know who's to blame in the end. Likewise, I have only experienced it in SE chat (which is great, since that kills mod status and kicks me out of rooms) - even amidst a turbulence of logouts on the Bridge, I stay logged into my Meta rooms without issue.

Comment: @GraceNote, What do I have to do with this? |:

Comment: @Rebecca Well, I *would* blame Yi Jiang for the wheel that tells me to blame you, but the wheel is saying that you're at fault for that, too. But in a serious sense, I thought you did have this issue, if not an early and less severe strain.

Comment: Chances are it's something along your network. Check your router settings?

Comment: @George I don't have a router to configure. Also I fail to see how a router would affect the session life cycle?

Comment: @radp firewall settings can hamper it, router settings can hamper it. I'm going through that at work right now. Every 5 minutes RDP is disconnecting and then reconnecting.  It's really noticeable for applications that have a constant connection (like chat and RDP).  Since you're on Mobile 3G, I'm not surprised you're getting dropped. It could be happening through your service provider.

Comment: @George If it was a firewall/router issue, wouldn't it affect both chat services and not just the Stack Exchange one?

Comment: @George Except 1) I said MSO chat doesn't have this problem, although much of the netcode is shared, 2) chat uses a polling method, _not_ a constant connection (unlike IRC).

Comment: I bet it _is_ indeed the 3G connection. I prefer to think of mine as ceil(2.5)G fwiw. I don't think it is anything you can do, sadly. You could try setting up some sort of heartbeat program on yours that pulls random google queries every thirty seconds, to a non-displayed screen, but that might trigger the googlesentry and you might have huge 3G service bills.

Comment: @GraceNote, It is a rare problem for me.  Every couple of weeks or so.  Certainly nothing like every x minutes.

Comment: *(off to buy a breathing mask)*

Comment: @Rebecca Ah, I see. It doesn't hit me very often, but on the days that it *does* hit, then it's not even 1 minute of peace for the duration. [Here's a transcript of my initial report](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2/2010/12/5), where just reporting it was a chore.

Comment: Oh then in that case I have ZERO IDEA. Sorry

Comment: We're looking at it

Comment: Is this still playing up?

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem too, getting logged out within *seconds*, while in the middle of typing a message, and I've come to the conclusion that it has something to do with Google's OpenID.  I say this because:

- Everybody it seems to happen to here is also using a Google OpenID;
- There was a previous issue where people (myself included) were also getting logged out of *SOFU/SE itself*, and the team investigated that one and found out that it was only with Google OpenIDs and could be mitigated by creating a Google profile;
- The problem went away for me last time when I created a Google profile and also switched my primary OpenID (although I switched it to another Google ID);
- I *also* get "quasi-logged-out" of Google services all the time - in other words, Google recognizes who I am but I inexplicably have to re-enter my password.

This may all be a grand coincidence, but I'm looking in Google's direction.  It *can't* just be an issue with SE chat, because it's only happening to a handful of people.  It must have something to do with cookies or sessions mysteriously expiring, and that's the responsibility of the OpenID provider.

If you already *have* a Google profile then at least try creating a totally different OpenID from a different provider and see if that solves it for you.

Comment: I've occasionally had it (though never as severely as described), and I don't use Google.

Comment: I use a Google Profile as my main OpenID provider.

Comment: @Michael: I think as a rule we're talking about *constant* logouts, not occasional ones.

Comment: @radp: Maybe I got lucky, or maybe having an alternate OpenID registered provides some sort of safety net, or maybe it was a side-effect of completely logging out of Google and then logging back in.  I don't know; I still suggest you try a different OpenID provider and at least rule out the possibility if you don't think that's it.

Comment: @Aarobot: Well, okay then. I guess I thought we were discussing the kind where you'd get logged out every ten or fifteen minutes for a period of several hours.

Comment: That is pretty bad, @Michael, although I've experienced what radp has, and it's even worse than that; it's every few minutes or even several times per minute in some instances.

Comment: I added a Yahoo OpenID to my account. Still no joy.

Answer (score 1):

I had it happen to me in just over 1 min tonight, in 5/6 tries. One time it was a bit over 3 mins.

I didn't realize that this issue had gotten so bad, as I've actually stopped using chat.se, except for quick check-ins with my moderator room.

I've also noticed that my avatar was faded-out upon returning to the room after being logged out of chat.

I am using Google for my OpenID provider, as well.